# Interchanging of values with conditions?

Tags: shell, awk, conditional-statements

I have a following file and i would like to swap the values which are in format of digits(up to 3 digits)@digits(up to 4 digits) followed by # or space/end of line.
If @ is followed by non digits then it shouldn't interchange them.

### Sample Input

```
cat file1
xyz xyz xyz 123@456#1@34#123@2
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
test test
123@456#1@34#123@212#3@456#1@34#123@2#123@xyzxyz xyz

xyz xyz xyz
```

**Sample output:**

---

```
xyz xyz xyz 456@123#34@1#2@123
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
test test
456@123#34@1#212@123#456@3#34@1#2@123#123@xyzxyz xyz

xyz xyz xyz
```

Have tried the following logic, seems like split is required in order interchange the values, but not able to check the condition along with how to save this in same field

```
awk '{for(a=1;a<=NF;a++){if($a~/@/){split($a,b,"[@#]");val1=b[1];val2=b[2];print val1,val2}}}' file1
123 456
123 456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple `gnu sed` should be able to do the job:

```sh
sed -E 's/\<([0-9]{1,3})@([0-9]{1,4})(#|$)/\2@\1\3/g' file

xyz xyz xyz 456@123#34@1#2@123
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
test test
456@123#34@1#212@123#456@3#34@1#2@123#123@xyzxyz xyz

xyz xyz xyz
```

Here, `\<` is used for word boundary.

Note that on BSD sed you have to use `[[:<:]]` for word boundary:

```sh
sed -E 's/[[:<:]]([0-9]{1,3})@([0-9]{1,4})(#|$)/\2@\1\3/g' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `\<`: Word boundary
- `([0-9]{1,3})`: Match 1 to 3 digits
- `@`: Match a `@`
- `([0-9]{1,4})`: Match 1 to 4 digits
- `(#|$)`: Match a `#` or end of line

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='([0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{1,4}#)+[0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{1,4}' '
{
  val=""
  delete arr
  delete arr2
  num=split(RT,arr,"#")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    valTemp=""
    split(arr[i],arr2,"@")
    valTemp=arr2[2]"@"arr2[1]
    val=(val?val "#":"")valTemp
  }
  ORS=val
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: this will change things like `1234@5678` while it's not digits{1,3}@digits{1,4}; as well as `xyz123@456` and doesn't change things like `023@456#`

Comment: @Bajajsahab, could you please confirm here if you are looking for number of digits like any digits can occur from 1 to 4 in counting and not the values 1 to 4? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: @αғsнιη, Ok, I am back now. That's why I always write in my answers that answer is as per shown samples only, else there will be lot of assumptions to make which we don't know what will be correct and what will be not :) IMHO I don't think `000@1111` should be changed to `111@000`(may be OP asked only for checking conditions but those conditions NOT applied on expected output I believe), that's not what is shown in OP's samples of output, I will wait for OP to confirm the same on this one, thank you.

Comment: I was bad about `000@1111` it should change, but `1111@000` should not (based on what OP said in _"`digits(up to 3 digits)@digits(up to 4 digits) `"_), but let s/he confirm; but your `RS` should be `RS='([0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{1,4}#)+|[0-9]{1,3}@[0-9]{1,4}'`; also you add extra @ in some cases like `110@111#<whitespace>` changes to `111@110#@`

Comment: @αғsнιη, ok with line `1111@000#bla@blabla` I tested my code and it didn't change it :) so regex is working fine as per shown samples and conditions mentioned by OP, cheers.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm more focused on the given conditions by the OP and for the general solution instead of just resolving the problem based on given samples only (which that is not what I always focus on) :D

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` for the [word `\b`oundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
sed -E 's/\b([[:digit:]]{1,3})@([[:digit:]]{1,4})(#|[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]*$)/\2@\1\3/g' infile
```

Input:

```
xyz123@456#1@34#1234@2 
0123@456# 123@456# 
123@456#1@34#123@212#3@456#1@34#123@2#123@xyzx
5678@124  111@110# 002@001 01@010 1111@000 
1111@000
```

Output:

```
xyz123@456#34@1#1234@2 
0123@456# 456@123# 
456@123#34@1#212@123#456@3#34@1#2@123#123@xyzx
5678@124  110@111# 001@002 010@01 1111@000 
1111@000
```